# Log4Net MemoryAppender seems to miss high speed log events

Tags: c#, winforms, log4net

I am using a log4net MemoryAppender to show my log4net output on a form text box.  The relevant part of my config file is:

```xml
<appender name="MemoryAppender" type="log4net.Appender.MemoryAppender" >
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level %date %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

The code that updates the form is fired by a timer and looks like:

```
var events = _memoryAppender.GetEvents();

foreach (var loggingEvent in events)
{
    textBoxOutput.Text += loggingEvent.Level + "  " + loggingEvent.MessageObject + Environment.NewLine;
}
_memoryAppender.Clear();
```

It is working, but when my application logs a lot of messages in a short period of time I don't seem to see them.  Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

As a workaround I am using [Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/howto/chainsaw.html) and a UDP appender:

```xml
   <appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO"/>
        <param name="LevelMax" value="ERROR"/>
    </filter>
    <param name="RemoteAddress" value="127.0.0.1" />
    <param name="RemotePort" value="8080" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j, log4net" />
</appender>
```

I like my own UI better, though, so I am still looking for answers.

Comment: In case you care, there is a developer snapshot of Chainsaw with a ton of new features, check it out here: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the following happens: While you are writing your log messages in the text box, new messages are logged. When you clear the messages in the appender you also remove these new messages, which are not written to the text box.

You could improve the situation by clearing the appender before starting to write messages to the text box but I think you should create your own memory appender and provide a method that returns the messages and clears the array in one step. Something like this:

```
public class MyMemoryAppender : MemoryAppender
{
    public LoggingEvent[] GetAndClearEvents()
    {
        lock (m_eventList.SyncRoot)
        {
            var events = (LoggingEvent[]) m_eventsList.ToArray(typeof(LoggingEvent));
            m_eventsList.Clear();
            return events;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  Sounds like good advice.  I'll check it out as soon as I am back at work.

Comment: I still could not get it to work, but the problem could very well be elsewhere in my project.  Thanks for the idea!